# I'm not able to execute insert command inside perl script?

Tags: perl, sql-server-2005

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;     

$fund=103;
$mobile_number1="7700009896";
$city_address="hello word";

$sql_query3=(qq{ exec "INSERT INTO [192.168.14.28].CommunicationLog.dbo.sms_processedfeeds (pf_Fund,pf_trtype,pf_acno,pf_ihno,pf_Mobile,pf_msgtrtype,pf_msg,pf_entdt) VALUES  ($fund,'CALL',0,NULL,'$mobile_number1','CALL','$city_address',Getdate())"});

my $sql_sms = $dbh->prepare($sql_query3);
$sql_sms->execute();
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
DBD::ODBC::db prepare failed: [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]The identifier that starts with 'INSERT INTO [192.168.14.28].CommunicationLog.dbo.sms_processedfeeds (pf_Fund,pf_trtype,pf_acno,pf_ihno,pf_Mobile,pf_msgtrtype,pf' is too long. Maximum length is 128. (SQL-42000)
[unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (SQL-42000) at Mobile_verification.pl line 8.
Can't call method "execute" on an undefined value at Mobile_verification.pl line 9.
```

Comment: I don't know `exec`, but the message says the first argument should be an identifier, not a SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with [`exec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx), but the message says the first argument should be an identifier, not a SQL query. If you meant to use the `exec` SQL command, you're misusing it.

But you say you want to perform an `INSERT`, so maybe you didn't mean to use `EXECUTE` at all. An `INSERT` would look like:

```
 my $stmt = "
    INSERT INTO [192.168.14.28].CommunicationLog.dbo.sms_processedfeeds (
              pf_Fund,
              pf_trtype,
              pf_acno,
              pf_ihno,
              pf_Mobile,
              pf_msgtrtype,
              pf_msg,
              pf_entdt
           ) VALUES (
              ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,Getdate()
           )
";
my $sth = dbh->prepare($stmt);
$sth->execute(
   $fund,
   'CALL',
   0,
   undef,
   '$mobile_number1',
   'CALL',
   $city_address,
);
```

Note: You could replace `prepare`+`execute` with `$dbh->do($stmt, undef, ...data...);`

Note: I'm assuming `[192.168.14.28].CommunicationLog.dbo.sms_processedfeeds` is a valid table designation.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `exec` and the nested quotes in the statement. Use this instead

```
my $mobile_number1_lit = $dbh->quote($mobile_number1);
my $city_address_lit   = $dbh->quote($city_address);
$sql_query3 = <<END_SQL;
INSERT INTO [192.168.14.28].CommunicationLog.dbo.sms_processedfeeds (pf_Fund, pf_trtype, pf_acno, pf_ihno, pf_Mobile, pf_msgtrtype, pf_msg, pf_entdt)
VALUES ($fund, 'CALL', 0, NULL, $mobile_number1_lit, 'CALL', $city_address_lit, Getdate())
END_SQL

my $sql_sms = $dbh->prepare($sql_query3);
$sql_sms->execute;
```

or, preferably, use placeholders in the `prepare` and pass the parameters to `execute`, like this

```
$sql_query3 = <<'END_SQL';
INSERT INTO [192.168.14.28].CommunicationLog.dbo.sms_processedfeeds (pf_Fund, pf_trtype, pf_acno, pf_ihno, pf_Mobile, pf_msgtrtype, pf_msg, pf_entdt)
VALUES (?, 'CALL', 0, NULL, ?, 'CALL', ?, Getdate())
END_SQL

my $sql_sms = $dbh->prepare($sql_query3);
$sql_sms->execute($fun, $mobile_number1, $city_address);
```